# ??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory

Tags: android, bluetooth, logcat, cyanogenmod

I am developing a new app about Bluetooth.

Because the Android Virtual Devices in android SDK can't open the Bluetooth ,I use my I5700 for Debug.

But , I can't get any log messages from Eclipse LogCat or CMD .
the only log message is the title :

> ??-?? ??:??:??.???:
>   INFO/(): Unable to
>   open log device '/dev/log/main': No
>   such file or directory

I searched stack Overflow and get an answer about it :
The Speedmod kernel,This has default Logging disabled. Re-enabled it in the TWEAKS menu.

My phone is samsung spica i5700,and I use CyanogenMod kernel , and this has also default Logging disabled, but I can't find where can I open it.

> windows 7
>
> adt 10.0
>
> samsung spica i5700

who can help me ? ：）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked the man who worked with samsung sipca i5700.

the YONIP Kernel made logcat disabled, and he fix YONIP Kernel now.

Have fun.