# "Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory"

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am new to Android development and bought a cheap Huawei Sonic (U8650 apparently) so I could test my first attempts at making an app on an actual device.

However, whenever I try to use 'adb logcat' or 'adb shell' then 'logcat' on the device I get:

```
Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory
```

I have already enabled Usb debugging in Settings -> Developer.

I just don't know enough about Android to know if this is something I can even fix.

I have found two other questions with similar problems:

[/dev/log/main not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867971/dev-log-main-not-found)

[??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692885/info-unknownunknown-unable-to-open-log-device-dev-lo)

...but they both turned out to be using some kind of non standard kernel that had logging disabled. Mine is a stock phone out of the box.

It's a very cheap but snappy Android 2.3 phone, so hopefully it wasn't a total waste of money.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When i thought all doors are closed, you opened a new one, hugs thanks :) u made my phone valuable again ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have actually found an answer for this finally!

I was having another aimless look to see if anything had been updated about this anywhere and came across a post on xda-developers about a slightly different Huawei device with the same problem.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17774398&postcount=93

It actually worked. I have complete logcat logging on my Huawei Sonic (U8650) now.

Three cheers for not giving up.

---

**Solution, copied from the xda (in case it is removed etc):**

```
There is a hidden service-menu where you can set loggin up. The
service-menu is started by "dialing" this phone number:

*#*#2846579#*#*
```

Comment: Also answered in another stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021939/what-to-do-if-manufacturer-removed-folders-under-dev-log-folder-means-no-logca

Comment: When I type the phone# sequence on either of my phones they both do the same thing: erase the ph# from the screen and do nothing...

Answer (score 73):

Dial this: `*#*#2846579#*#*` 
Service menu will appear. 
Go to "ProjectMenu" -> "Background Setting" -> "Log Setting"

Open "Log switch" and set it to ON.  
Open "Log level setting" and set the log level you wish.

Reboot the phone.

Comment: Nothing happens on HTC Incredible S Custom CM10.1 JB =(

Comment: Don't forget to turn off fastboot before rebooting your phone.

Comment: Nothing happened for me because I've typed `*#*#` after the numbers instead of `#*#*`

Comment: anyone know the hidden menu for samsung s8?

Answer (score 33):

1. Open: `/system/etc/init.d/×××` （not the same file on different ROMs, find the right file）
2. Find the line that says: `rm /dev/log/main`
3. Change the line to: `# rm /dev/log/main` (comments out the line, `rm` = remove, in case you were wondering)
4. Save and reboot

Comment: Thanks to this method.  In my phone(rom:4.0.4),/system/etc/init.d/××× the xxx file is 'speedy'

Comment: Thanks! In LG p970 (Optimus Black) using "Unoffical CM9" as of today, you have to comment this out in 02logger and 12cleaner.

Comment: i can't change anything in those file :(

Comment: @haythemsouissi are you root?

Comment: Thanks! For my Vega iron, xxxx is 69removelogger => clearly name :)

Comment: thanks a lot of maan! that work for my device: gt-i9500 ozcanRom

Answer (score 17):

I'm sharing my case and solution:

My cellphone had a jellybean version oriented to performance (To be exact a Slim Bean ROM) with a Semaphore kernel (You can recognize it because when the cellphone is starting, the semaphore logo is shown). These kind of ROM have by default disabled the logging so I had to download the Semaphore Manager application (You can download it from [here](http://www.all-apk.com/tag/semaphore-manager-apk-download/)). After that, in the section "Modules" I had to turn on the Logger option as it is shown in the picture

[image]

Restart and the logcat should be working now!

Comment: exact solution for me on Samsung Galaxy S - Captivate, with Slim Bean 4.2.2 and Semaphore Kernel.

Comment: Hmm.. anyone got an answer for S8500 wave device running android 4.4 tigrouzen ROM ?None of the previous work. Tried manually putting that file in its place got back read: Unexpected length error.

Answer (score 2):

I have a custom rom on my Samsung Captivate, but my approach may work for others as well:

Open up CMD or Terminal and type:

```
adb shell
logcat-enable
reboot
```

The rom I have is Continuum v6.1, but this still may work for others.
If you have the terminal emulator on the phone, you also may be able to do:

```
logcat-enable
```

and then just reboot the phone. I didn't try that, but it probably would work too. My phone is also rooted - don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ulidtko I"m not surprised. I guess it's a function of certain kernels. Some include the logcat-enable and logcat-disable commands, but stock kernels likely would not. If I figure something more out, I'll post it.

Answer (score 2):

it was enough to restart the Huawei device

```
adb shell
reboot
```

Comment: $ reboot shows me `reboot: Operation not permitted` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same problem.
Someone from xda-developers wrote something as follows in msg #33

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1169869&page=4

> One of the reason it can't be rooted is this phone had removed the
>   "Logcat" mechanism from android. So, this makes most of rooting ways
>   malfunction.

Maybe right maybe wrong i don't know.Anyway it gives some idea about the case.

Comment: Yeah, I have actually managed to root the device (using the instructions in that same thread, actually: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16107543&postcount=24), but I guess I would need some way of replacing the ROM currently on it with one that hasn't had logcat stripped...

Comment: I tried Roms here :(http://wiki.modaco.com/index.php/Huawei_Firmware_U8650).It is said Spanish Yoigo works but my device is set to work with ROM of selling carrier so caught up with a sim lock.I managed a way using java.util.logging API and wrote a piece of code to dump logs into a file on sdcard.