# "Unable to open log device 'dev/log/main'" error?

Tags: android, logcat, galaxy

I am using a rooted galaxy s2 4.0.3 and I recently tried to write an android app. I tried to use logcat in eclipse and it printed the following reply:

`unable to open log device 'dev/log/main'  No such file or directory`

I went through the answers on the forum; some wrote to change files in the `init.d` folder but I don't have such a folder. I don't use Huawei so special code won't help here. I even tried to install logcat applications on my device, but they didn't work either!

Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried `adb logcat` too?

Comment: yes , i still get the                                            "unable to open log device 'dev/log/main' No such file or directory"

Comment: May be same as this:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941710/unable-to-open-log-device-dev-log-main-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Dial this: `*#*#2846579#*#*`

Service menu will appear.

Go to "ProjectMenu" -> "Background Setting" -> "Log Setting"

Open "Log switch" and set it to ON.

Open "Log level setting" and set the log level you wish.

Reboot the phone.

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to restart the Huawei device:

```
adb shell
reboot
```

I guess manual restart would worked as well.