# Viewing app in LogCat in Android

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

In Eclipse I am debugging my app but in LogCat I don't see my app under the column Application. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

go to DDMS -> Devices and select your emulator.then logcat will show logs for that device emulator.

Comment: Not using emulator. Using a real device.

Comment: u can select the ur real device from this path as well.it will show all devices abd emulator currently connected with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Click DDMS.
->Select DeviceName.
--->Select App Name.

Logcat will be Show.

If Not the 
GoTo 
Eclipse-->Window-->Reset Perspective.
It`s Work.

Comment: I selected my device name and I clearly see the app is debugging from the Debug perspective. However the LogCat now just shows: ?:??: W/?(?): Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory

Comment: Use this see the logcat nothing any other ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Huawei device and this is a known problem. Solution can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12457005/753632