# Logcat doesn't work for my new Samsung Galaxy Note

Tags: android, eclipse

In my logcat I am getting this message:

```
?:??: W/?(?): Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory
```

After I ran my application in my Galaxy Note via eclipse, I ran it correctly but I am not getting any logs in my logcat.

Also I am running Eclipse in my Macbook Pro (i don't know if this information will help).

How can I fix this?

Comment: windows > preferences > show view > other > devices . now select your device . logcat will start working .

Comment: yes i am seeing my Galaxy Note in the list of my devices. I click on it. The problem in logcat i don't see any of my messages

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941710/unable-to-open-log-device-dev-log-main-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Is the phone running a custom build or have you rooted it ? Try the solution in this related thread - ["Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941710/unable-to-open-log-device-dev-log-main-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: i can't get the service menu.
when i dialed this *#*#2846579#*#* in phone app, then click on call. doesn't work on samsung.

Comment: Have you tried the other suggestions like removing the line that removes this directory ? (rm /dev/log/main). If you have root access you can always create this directory through the adb shell.

Answer (score 0):

In case selecting your device doesn't work, try to run eclipse -clean from the command line. it should do the job.