# log.d doesn't appear in Logcat

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools, android-debug

I have two smartphones one Nexus 4 and one Vodafone Smart 3 (TLC - Alcatel v975). In my Sourcecode I have two log.d and if I make the debugging on Nexus the log.d appear in Logcat, but when I'm using Vodafone Smart 3 , log.d doesn't appear in Logcat ... My Sourcecode is the following :

```
public void savetime(View view){

    Integer hour= mitsos.getCurrentHour();
    Integer minutes=mitsos.getCurrentMinute();
    Log.d("mitsos","hour "+hour);
    Log.d("mitsos","minutes"+minutes);}
```

Comment: "Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime". quoting from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html. "Error, warning and info logs are always kept". Use `Log.i()`.

Comment: And why does it happen only with my Vodafone smart 3 and not with Nexus ?!

Comment: no idea about that haven't come across such a situation till now/

Answer (score 4):

Some device not print debug log, but you can use below method

```
Log.wtf("tag","msg");
```

its working for me.

Comment: I found it working as well. What a hilarious Sh*t by google :D

Comment: This looks like a joke, but works like a charm!!! =) Awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

Try ["Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941710/unable-to-open-log-device-dev-log-main-no-such-file-or-directory/12457005), set the log level.

If you don't see the service menu, make sure that your ROM support it, otherwise you maybe need to use another ROM (usually official) or just use `Log.i()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `System.out.println("")` as well for wrting to log cats.I have also come across with the same problem on my device.Sometime device did log but sometime didnt. but `System.out.println("")` always works for me.