# Android Studio (1.3.2) Logcat doesn't work with external device

Tags: debugging, android-studio, logcat

I'm testing out an app on an external Android device Alcatel OneTouch), but the logcat will not display anything from it. No crash reports, status updates, etc.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show) SO post,

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511867/android-logcat-is-empty-when-debug-with-device-in-android-studio) SO post,

and many like them. But all to no avail. Restarting the logcat doesn't work, nor does tampering with any of the settings.

**See solution below**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this question, because it is a very specific series of steps required for me to get any data showing in the logcat, and maybe you're having the same issue testing on external devices.

The order is:

- Launch app on external device
- Start new GenyMotion emulator (shouldn't matter which one)
- Change logcat to show "No Filters"
- Switch logcat to emulator (should start showing data within logcat from emulator)
- Switch logcat back to external device

And voila! It should be pouring out data from the external device. It only works on the "No Filters" setting, so it is a little tedious to find crash reports and anything else pertaining to the app, but it's the only way I can get the logcat to work with my external device.