# Debugger shows empty when using debug mode "Android Studio"

Tags: java, android, xml, debugging, android-studio

[image]
Hi Every body when i trying to debug my app variables section shows " Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8613', transport: 'socket'".
I tried to force debug mode in manifest but same problem.
and i before that it was working good.
Please help;

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511867/android-logcat-is-empty-when-debug-with-device-in-android-studio

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show

Comment: i checked it before but no one helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it by Opening new project and copy my codes to it and its worked.