# Logcat shows nothing when connected to my device but shows when connected to an emulator

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am using Honor 5C. Since I have bought this phone I am not able to catch any error or potential information which helps me solving the bugs using the logcat as it shows nothing when connected to it. But on the other side I am able to see the log in the logcat when testing the app using emulator namely Genymotion. It's like a mystery for me. Even being an Android Developer I am not able to figure it out. So I need your help. I have tried all the tips and tricks related to the question found on Stack Overflow but my problem is different. Please do help.

Comment: have you tried to change device in Android monitor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Logcat is empty when debug with device in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511867/android-logcat-is-empty-when-debug-with-device-in-android-studio)

Comment: have you try `adb devices`? did your device listed?

Answer (score 1):

1. turn on developer options on the android device.
2. Make sure your device is not connected as a media device. (Some device work if turn on)
3. enable check box for stay awake.
4. enable check box for USB debugging.
5. open cmd
6. adb kill-server
7. adb start-server
8. adb devices

Your device will be listed

if your devices is connected but no logcat. Please invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Where should I open the cmd? Or should I open the terminal in the AS itself?

Comment: Android studio itself

Comment: In the terminal it says -  'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: ZeroOne I tried your steps and found somwhere working but then I intentionally tried to create an NullPointerException error but I did not received any error in the logcat. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be occur due to absence of adb driver of your device ...
Your can download [pdanet+](http://pdanet.co/a/) which will automatically install adb driver for your device.

Answer (score 0):

After a simple stack search I found the tricky solution for my device

[Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android/10963065#10963065)

It works for Huawei device (Honor 5C (mine!)).

There are no such USB Drivers available for Huawei deives. Even the support team said they can't help it.